# Need PHP Date advanced and tricky coding

Tags: php, datetime

Please try to understand the problem first.

I want PHP code to find the difference between two dates (number of days) in php and store the result as numeric/int value in a variable in php

I know date_diff() function will be used. But How ?? 
I'm using wampserver 2.2 on Windows 7
My PHP version is 5.3.12 
Please help

Comment: "numeric/int" so which is it? Also, days, weeks, months or minutes? An Example would be good.

Comment: @Philipp days in number

Comment: added an answer using the `DateTime` class and `date_diff()` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-01-31');

$date2 = new DateTime('2014-02-04');

$diff = date_diff($date, $date2, true);
$difference = $diff->format("%a"); // 4
```

This will give you the difference in days. If you want something else than days you can see the possible formats here: http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

As you can see, the function `date_diff()` is very easy to use. It will return you an `DateInterval` object, which you can then format to give you the desired result.

Comment: I cold not  understand the statement
var_dump($diff->format("%a"));
Actually I need the number of days between two dates to be assigned to a numeric variable.so that I can use tha  variable later in the script

Comment: @RockyAlex It was just to display the value which is returned by `$diff->format("%a")`. If you take the snippet as it is now `$difference` will have the value 4 and you can work with it like with any other variable

Comment: @RockyAlex So is there a problem/error with this code?

Comment: Thank u  it worked ultimately. Actually I was having some other logical errors which I fixed today.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution that I can think of is converting the date to `timestamp`and then getting the difference. An example is :-

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //I know it's same, it will be different in your case.
//conver it to timestamp now
$date1_timestamp = strtotime($date1);
$date2_timestamp = strtotime($date2);
//calculate difference.
$difference = $date2_timestamp - $date2_timestamp;
//the difference variable holds an int value.
//however, if you want to convert it back to readable date, you can do it like this
$difference_readable_date = date('m/d/Y', $difference);
```

Comment: I need the number of days

Comment: To yield the number of days take the above result and divide by 86,400.

Answer (score -1):

my function for all the odds one or 2 times , date or timestamp..

```
 function time_Diff($time2_, $time1_ = false) {
        $date1 = new \DateTime();
        if ($time1_) {
            $time1 = preg_match('/[-\/]/', $time1_) ? strtotime($time1_) : $time1_;
            $date1->setTimestamp($time1);
        }
        $date2 = new \DateTime();
        $time2 = preg_match('/[-\/]/', $time2_) ? strtotime($time2_) : $time2_;
        $date2->setTimestamp($time2);
        $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
        $diffrent_ = $interval->format('%Y Years %m Months %d Days %H:%I:%S');
        $diffrent = str_replace(['00 Years', ' 0 Months', ' 0 Days', '00:00:00'], '', $diffrent_);
        $returner = str_replace(['01 Years', ' 1 Months', ' 1 Days'], ['01 Year', ' 1 Month', ' 1 Day'], $diffrent);
        return trim($returner);
    }
```